# Textbox validation forcing error

Tags: c#, textbox, httprequest, validate-request

Vista, visual web developer express 2010, c#, asp.net, webforms.  Running program with ctrl-F5.  I'm the only person who will ever run this program ... and it will only ever run on my laptop using a local database.

Writing app to download web pages, view them, (do some analysis), log some results.
I found code to download pages - works well.  I then set the text property of a textbox equal to the string contents of the page.  That part also works.  Then I went to run the code again, BUT the contents of the textbox gets validated and results in an error message.

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$tbPageContents="
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI...").
```

I can run the code over and over without problem - so long as I don't display the results in a textbox.  I tried a couple different solutions:

1. I tried enabled="false" attribute in the textbox ... this allows me to view the first part of the code, but since the textbox is not enabled, I can't scroll up and down and look at the file.  So this doesn't really solve the problem.
2. I tried setting validateRequest="false" in the page directive and in system.web (as per http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation), but so far as I can tell it has no effect.  That is, I still get the error.
3. I tried using html encoding the string contents before I put them into the textbox.  That works on the display ... but it doesn't fix the problem that it fails on the next iteration of the problem.
4. I thought about catching the error and ignoring it, but the validation seems to happen before it executes my code-behind.

I don't actually HAVE to print the page to a window to do the analysis, but it would be very helpful if I could look at this stuff all at once or in snippets.  I could just do a page source from a browser.  I'm not sure ... maybe that's the preferred solution.

I'm really surprised that option #2 did not work, as that seems to be the recommended solution.

Here's the page directive I use:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="wan._Default" validateRequest="false" %>
```

Is there something else one needs to do to stop the validateRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also use `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in your web.config file. This instructs ASP.NET to change its validation mode to version 2.0.

You may also like to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client).

Comment: That's it. Will accept answer when it lets me.  I thought I did use that command previously, but in lieu of the other statement, not along with it.  Very good! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is .NET 4, you may also need to add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to your web.config